# Making a backspace button for a calculator

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, calculator

I am making an iOS calculator and it I'm having minor difficulties with the backspace button (for deleting the last number of the value displayed on a label).

To get the current value on the label I use

```
    double currentValue = [screenLabel.text doubleValue]
```

Following other questions, I tried something like

```
-(IBAction)backspacePressed:(id)sender
{
NSMutableString *string = (NSMutableString*)[screenLabel.text];

int length = [string length];

NSString *temp = [string substringToIndex:length-1]
;

[screenLabel.text setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",temp]];

}
```

But it does not work,

(Xcode says "**setText is deprecated**", "**NSString may not respond to setText**" and that an **identifier is expected** in the first line of code inside the IBAction)

and I do not really understand this code to make it work by myself.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
[screenLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",temp]];
```

Your Xcode clearly says that you are trying to call `setText' method on an`NSString`where as you should be calling that on a`UILabel`. Your`screenLabel.text`is retuning an`NSString`. You should just use`screenLabel`alone and should call`setText` on that.

Just use,

```
NSString *string = [screenLabel text];
```

The issue with that was that, you are using `[screenLabel.text];` which is not correct as per objective-c syntax to call `text` method on `screenLabel`. Either you should use,

```
NSString *string = [screenLabel text];
```

or

```
NSString *string = screenLabel.text;
```

In this method, I dont think you need to use `NSMutableString`. You can just use `NSString` instead.

In short your method can be written as,

```
-(IBAction)backspacePressed:(id)sender
{
   NSString *string = [screenLabel text];
   int length = [string length];
   NSString *temp = [string substringToIndex:length-1];
   [screenLabel setText:temp];
}
```

As per your question in comments(which is deleted now), if you want to display zero when there are no strings present, try,

```
-(IBAction)backspacePressed:(id)sender
{
   NSString *string = [screenLabel text];
   int length = [string length];
   NSString *temp = [string substringToIndex:length-1];

   if ([temp length] == 0) {
     temp = @"0";
   }
   [screenLabel setText:temp];
}
```

Comment: Or skip the setText method and just use: "screenLabel.text = temp;"?